# How to resolve removal app because of "use of sms or call log" permission?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Today our app was removed from Play Store due to a permission violation.
It does not have the SMS or CALL LOG permission. 
Below are the list of permissions. What is the issue here?

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PROFILE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
```

Answer (score 1):

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"

If you use this permission. You can follow Google [SMS/Call Log permissions.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)
Otherwise Remove this permission.

Answer (score 1):

You are initiate a call by adding `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` and that you need to remove from manifest file and used `Dial Intent` and it doesn't require the `CALL_PHONE` permission.

Visit official link for more information  [Click Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Comment: We have removed the CALL_PHONE but when I upload the new APK, I'm still seeing the below error along with permission declaration forms. 
New permissions requests (1 permission)
android.permission.READ_SMS

Thanks for the info.

Comment: For  `android.permission.READ_SMS ` you need to register your application as default SMS handler. you need remove this permission if added and used `SMS Retriever API`.